# Rename or re-tag [Counter]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

So apparently we have a tag [counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/counter) which is heavily abused for all kinds of questions using counters. The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/counter/info) does however say that the tag is for a very specific use, namely some class in Python. Looking at the questions with this tag, very few are actually about Python.

So I propose that the tag gets renamed, perhaps to [python-counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-counter)? I don't know enough about Python to tell if the tag is useful or not. Perhaps it could as well get burninated?

Comment: With it's current name, no wonder it gets abused. Renaming it seems like a good idea.

Comment: I'm not even sure if it was originally intended to be a Python-only tag. That excerpt is horrible.

Comment: The only way out I see of this is: blacklist counter, create python-counter and slowly retag counter questions (should be easy as searching python+counter), and remove everything else

Comment: Note that the excerpt seems plagiarized by the linked site. And I have no idea why they chose to link to this random pymotw site instead of the official documentation...

Comment: We have a specific tag for questions related to CSS counters ([tag:css-counter]) and so questions related to it can be re-tagged.

Comment: I have no counter-argument...

Comment: There is also the currently existing [python-collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-collections) tag which refers to the python module which contains the `Counter` class which could/should be used instead of creating a python-counter tag.

Comment: @Gavin are we really down that road? Creating a tag for each class we find on any library?

Comment: @Braiam That's what I mean, I would argue that there is no need for a python-counter tag - there's a tag at the module level (which I'm not even sure if we would need that - 3 questions so far this year), but it seems others are recommending creating a new tag specifically for the class level (Counter) underneath that. To my mind given the questions associated with the counter tag, cleaning up the usage guidance to make it non language specific makes more sense.

Comment: It would be great if some people who participate in the Python tag would post an answer and state the usefulness of the tag. If it is indeed useless, we can change this to a burninate-request. I don't know Python so I will not take any initiatives here.

Comment: The Python Counter class gets a lot of use, and we get plenty of questions about it, but I don't see the value in having a tag for it.

Comment: Since June 19th there have been 30 questions tagged `counter`. Only 9 of them are Python questions and only 5 of those were questions about the `collections.Counter` class. Anyone who has a question about `collections.Counter` is better off finding help with the `python` tag, and as far as I'm concerned this tag should be burninated.

Comment: To be clear what is being asked here: the tag [tag:counter] is not necessarily Python-centric, it shouldn't be Python-centric, and I agree it wouldn't have much value if it was. There are plenty of uses of the same meaning across all languages, I tried to inventory uses of the term 'counter'. For example, 'wordcount' is near-synonymous with 'counter' (with string keys) [at least in languages with a counter builtin]. @MoxieBall: I think you're missing this context. This question is asking to resolve what the tag should mean, not just a simple up-or-down vote on a Python-centric [tag:counter].

Comment: ...hence whether the tag [tag:counter] is currently being applied much is irrelevant (anyway most people incl. me don't know about it). The question is *what should it be used for?/(if it should exist)*

Comment: The current question statement is misrepresenting: The tag wiki **doesn't** say that the tag is *"for a very specific use, namely some class in Python."* It says it's for generic language-independent use *"a container that keeps track of how many times equivalent values are added"*. It merely mentions the corresponding Python class. There are equally Java, PERL, etc. implementations... so please edit the tag wiki already. 'Counter' is a generic concept; the fact that the Python implementation happens to be called 'Counter' is not the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

First let's inventory the distinct uses of 'counter':

- a) a simple (integer) counter or timer (with one single value). Generically found in any (shell-/scripting-/compiled) language.
- b) **CSS counter** "variable maintained by CSS whose value may be incremented
  by CSS rules to track how many times they're used" e.g. list auto-numbering
- c) sometimes used in the sense **'loop counter/index' in for/foreach/while-loop**
- d) **a container to keep track of how many times specific values occur**. It can be used to implement the same algorithms for which bag or multiset data structures are commonly used in other languages.

  - the keys can be strings/ words/ integers/ categoricals/ any hashable object
  - e.g. word counts, grocery lists etc.
  - the Python implementation is `collections.Counter`. (What are the equivalents in PERL, Ruby, R, Java, C, C++ STL...?)
- e) **in SQL and no-SQL databases** in a somewhat similar sense to d), although it may be atomic, and may support concurrency

Now as to which are distinct, and which do/ do not deserve a separate tag:

- a) is pretty trivial and probably doesn't deserve any tag
- b) is very different to the other meanings, and either deserves [css-counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-counter), or at minimum should be untagged [counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/counter) to avoid all the confusion coming from CSS/JS
- c) questions on loop index should probably be untagged [counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/counter) and tagged `for/foreach/while`
- d) seems a legitimate (language-independent) case for [counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/counter)

  - There are not currently many instances of tag [counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/counter) for d), but not many people were aware the tag existed, and it had no description. Python questions involving 'word count' are equivalent. Also the subset of the [python-collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-collections) questions that relate to `Counter`.
- Does e) have sufficient commonality to d)? Should it/ not be tagged [counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/counter)? Database people please comment.